# Get timezone id in c++ winrt

Tags: c++, flutter, timezone, windows-runtime

I am learning `c++ winrt` to develop an app in `Flutter`. I can not find out how to get timezone id in windows which is in this kinda format: "Western Standard Time". I tried `DateTime.now().timezonename` but it is just giving the display name. Which means that if the language is Russian, for example, I get the timezone name in russian.  How can I get the `TimeZoneId` in `windows c++` so that I will always get the same English Language Timezone name?

Comment: By 'TimeZoneId', are you referring to a 3 character long identifier for the timezone? You may want to take a look at GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation (available on both Win32 and UWP) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-getdynamictimezoneinformation

Comment: No. I am referring the actual timezone like 'West Asian Standard Time'. But it should be always the same. I have edited my question to have more clarity

Comment: Time-related functions in WinRT/.Net will be localized. Now, if you just want to identity the timezone you can use the offset value or the id field. But, if you need the display name always in English, an old-school approach is getting the identifier from the registry – ‘Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones’ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_TimeZoneInfo_GetSystemTimeZones . I will send a full answer later today so I can be more helpful.